# Django raw sql problems with complex query

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

I have following query:

```
    keyWordsAllStr = ", ".join(keyWordsAll)

    main_query = Transactions.objects.raw(
        '''
        with cte0 as (
            select split_part(analytics_debet, ',', 1) as name
            from orm_analytics_transactions
            where account_debet like '103%%' and account_credit not like '10%%'
            and analytics_debet not in 
            ( %(keyWordsAllStr)s )
            and period >= %(min_date)s and period <= %(max_date)s
            and project_id = %(project_id)s
            group by analytics_debet
            order by sum(value_debet) DESC
            limit 7
            ),
            cte05 as (
                select case 
                when split_part(analytics_debet, ',', 1) not in (select name from cte0)
                    then 'Other' else split_part(analytics_debet, ',', 1) end
                as name
                from orm_analytics_transactions
                where account_debet like '103%' and account_credit not like '10%'
                and analytics_debet not in 
                ( %(keyWordsAllStr)s )
                and period >= %(min_date)s and period <= %(max_date)s
                and project_id = %(project_id)s
            ),
            cte1 as (   
            select d.dt as date, c.name
            from 
                (
                    select dt::date 
                    from generate_series('2022-03-01', '2023-02-01', '1 month'::interval) dt
                ) d
            cross join 
                (
                select distinct name 
                from cte05
                ) c
            ), 
            cte2 as  
            (
                select split_part(analytics_debet, ',', 1) as name, date_trunc('month', period)::date, sum(value_debet)
                from orm_analytics_transactions
                where account_debet like '103%%' and account_credit not like '10%%'
                and analytics_debet not in 
                ( %(keyWordsAllStr)s )
                and period >= %(min_date)s and period <= %(max_date)s
                and project_id = %(project_id)s
                group by 1,2
            )
        select c1.date, c1.name, coalesce(c2.sum, 0) as value
        from cte1 c1
        left join cte2 c2
        on c1.date = c2.date_trunc and c1.name = c2.name
        order by c1.name
        ;
        ''',
        params={
        "min_date": min_date,
        "max_date": max_date,
        "keyWordsAllStr": keyWordsAllStr,
        "project_id" : project_id,
        },
    )
```

when I try to execute it with:

`list(main_query)`

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/py/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: argument formats can't be mixed

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/py/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1484, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/py/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1471, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/py/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1494, in iterator
    query = iter(self.query)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/py/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 110, in __iter__
    self._execute_query()
  File "/py/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 150, in _execute_query
    self.cursor.execute(self.sql, params)
  File "/py/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/py/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/py/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/py/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/py/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/py/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: argument formats can't be mixed
```

I've ran this query with psql (without filtering min_date, max_date) and it works just fine. I also tried to remove all filtering and params in django query, no effect.
DB is postgres
I am not even sure what django.db.utils.ProgrammingError means, traceback is hard to comprehend.

Comment: Have you tried to replace value of your param with static value for testing ? I suppose there are errors in param values probably

Comment: @LucasGrugru sure, i even tried to remove all params by replacing them with static values, didn't help

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it. It was a dumb typo in cte05, it should have been

```
'103%%' and account_credit not like '10%%'
```

instead of

```
'103%' and account_credit not like '10%'
```